# To soon to attempt using Django-Piston with OAuth-2 for my API in production?

Tags: django, oauth-2.0, django-piston

We've currently got a Django application that uses Piston to serve a number of API endpoints, which perform a mix of reading and writing data from the the application. Adding an authentication layer, probably OAuth-2 is the next task in our dev. list.

Should we proceed with the Django-Piston combo, using whatever inbuilt OAuth-2 functionality Piston has, or look for other alternatives?

I'm also interested in a list of sites using Django-Piston with OAuth-2 in production. I've already found http://www.slideshare.net/tomatohater/dcpython-architecture-at-pbs-jun-7-2011 which was quite interesting.

Answer (score 2):

I recently got the OAuth-2 included in Piston working on an API that is in development.  We decided to go with a different method for data validation / verification but it the bundled Oauth-2 was working quite nicely.

Comment: Thanks! To clarify, are you saying you are still using Piston's inbuilt OAuth-2 features for authentication, but something else non-Piston related for validating data?